# How to make my Python password cracker operate more efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

A little while ago I got interested in making a pseudo-password cracker.
So, here's some code:

```
list = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] # giving it a list 

passlength = int(input('Length of string: ')) # length of code or no of objects
aspass = '' # empty string acts as assumed password
passs = input('Please input password ') # he infamous password
b = [] # the list that will stores randomly generated passwords as values
attempt = 0
digits = 0   
o = True
while o:
    for k in range(0, passlength): # run this loop as many times as the length of password
        x = str(random.choice(list))#the attempted upon digit in the password
        aspass += x
        digits += 1 # counts the step the cracker is on
        #print(aspass)
        if(len(aspass) > passlength or aspass in b):
            digits = 0
            attempt += 1
            break
        else:
            continue
        #b.append(aspass)
    if(aspass == passs):
        break
        o = False
        end()
    else:
        b.append(aspass)
        aspass = ''
        continue
```

The thing here is, everything works and it generates 2 string password petty well. However, if length exceeds 2 or 3 strings. Well, it kind of moves at snail pace. Then I got an idea, if I could save the randomly generated password in the "b" list that I made and make sure that the passwords in that list are not repeated in the process then i think it will run significantly faster.

As I am a total beginner I am out of ideas how to make it faster any other way. What things can I try (e.g. importable modules) to improve this?

Comment: Have you thought about the probabilities at work here? E.g. How many possible passwords you have with a length of 4?

Comment: Possibilities of work? I don't think i am old enough but, as it is for each letter of the string i gave it 36 possibilities. So, for a password with 2 letters it is 36×36 that is 36 squared, for a 3 lettered one it will be 36×36×36 or 36 cube, as such for a 4 letter one it will be 36 to the power 4. Which is about 1,679,616 combinations.

Comment: I know it seems to be inefficiant at first but with improvements i think it maybe just make it or if it totally doesn't work maybe some other method i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password cracking is not an easy job. Think about the search space you have to go through as the length of the password grows. Your list of the possible characters contains 26 letters and 10 digits (by the way you can use `string.digits` and `string.ascii_lowercase`). So, for the first character in your password there are 36 options. The second has 36 options, the 3rd has 36 options and so on. Therefor, for a password of length `n` you will have 3^n options. As you can quickly see, this number is growing extremely rapidly even for small numbers.

Your method of cracking the password is called [Brute-force attack](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Brute-force_attack) and it's extremely inefficient, especially considering the fact that most password are not stored as plain text but as hashed string.

**Few other notes:**

1. You variables names are not great. Most of them are meaningless and it makes your code much harder to understand.
2. You select random string instead of going through all the possible options in order. You have no way to cover all the options using this method. You can use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for iterating over all the options.
3. Don't use parenthesis in `if` statements, it's not the Python way. Please.

Comment: Thx for the quick feedback! Really appreciate it. I will surely try the itertools.permutations method you mentioned and as i am new to python (hasn't even been a month since i started) i am not so sure of the style to code in python. I personally use one word variables (x, y, z etc) i know they are difficult to understand but makes typing them easier. Anyway, thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
chars_list = list(chars)

password = pyautogui.password("Enter a Password : ")

guess_password = ""

while(guess_password != password):
    guess_password = random.choices(chars_list, k=len(password))

    print("DECRYPTING"+ str(guess_password)+ "PASSWORD")

    if(guess_password == list(password)):
        print("Your password is : "+ "".join(guess_password))
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

i make a program i want make GUI but if you need it you can use it from command lilne

```
 try:
    import string
except:
    print("please install strings lib with command <sudo pip3 install ")
try:
    import random
except:
    print("please install random lib with command <sudo pip3 install random>1")
try:
    import os
except:
    print("pleas install the os lib with command <sudo pip install os>")


def switch_case_no():
    dict_no = {"no": 0, "n": 0, "No": 0, "N": 0, "NO": 0}
    return dict_no


def switch_case_yes():
    dict_yes = {"yes": 1, "y": 1, "Yes": 1, "Y": 1, "YES": 1}
    return dict_yes


int_list = str(["1"+"2"+"3"+"4"+"5"+"6"+"7"+"8"+"9"+"0"])
sym_list = str(["~"+"!"+"@"+"#"+"$"+"%"+"^"+"&"+"*"+"("+")"+"_"+"+"+"|"+"?"+">"+"<"])
i = int_list
s = sym_list
l = string.ascii_lowercase
u = string.ascii_uppercase
list_int_1 = tuple(f"{i}")
list_sym_1 = tuple(f"{s}")
list_str_l_1 = tuple(f"{l}")
list_str_u_1 = tuple(f"{u}")


def checker(this_list):  # function to check and generate password list
    x = False  # loop broker
    while not x:  # start of the loop
        password = "".join(random.sample(this_list, k=len1))
        print(f">>>>>>!!!{password}!!!<<<<<<<\r", end="")
        if password == entry:
            print(f"the password is : " "\n""*****>>>>>>>>{password}<<<<<<<<*****\n created by PeterHattson")
            x = True
            try:
                os.system("beep -f 759 -l 400")
            except Exception:
                print("the system beep has not founded !!!!")
            break  # end of the while loop


entry = input("inter your pass >>>>  ")  # you can change this line with any login page that you want
ask_user_int = input("you password has an integer ??? ")
if ask_user_int in switch_case_yes():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password contain with integers <<<<")
elif ask_user_int in switch_case_no():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password will not contain with integers <<<<")
else:
    print("please just use yes/y or no/n ")
ask_user_sym = input("your password has a special symbols ??? ")
if ask_user_sym in switch_case_yes():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password contain with symbols <<<<")
elif ask_user_sym in switch_case_no():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password will not contain with symbols <<<<")
else:
    print("please just use yes/y or no/n ")
ask_user_str_l = input("did your password contain with lower case alphabet ????")
if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password contain with lower case alphabet <<<<")

elif ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password will not  contain with  lower case alphabet <<<<")
else:
    print("please just use yes/y or no/n ")
ask_user_str_u = input("did your password contain with upper case alphabet ????")
if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password contain with upper case alphabet  <<<<")
elif ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
    print(">>>>ckuF Your password will not  contain with upper case alphabet  <<<<")
else:
    print("please just use yes/y or no/n ")
len1 = len(entry)

if ask_user_int in switch_case_yes():
    if ask_user_sym in switch_case_yes():
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_int_1 + list_sym_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_int_1 + list_str_l_1 + list_sym_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_int_1 + list_str_l_1 + list_str_u_1 + list_sym_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_int_1 + list_str_u_1 + list_sym_1)
if ask_user_int in switch_case_no():
    if ask_user_sym in switch_case_yes():
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_sym_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_str_l_1 + list_sym_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_str_l_1 + list_str_u_1 + list_sym_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_str_u_1 + list_sym_1)
if ask_user_int in switch_case_yes():
    if ask_user_sym in switch_case_no():
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_int_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_str_l_1 + list_int_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_str_l_1 + list_str_u_1 + list_int_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_str_u_1 + list_int_1)
if ask_user_int in switch_case_no():
    if ask_user_sym in switch_case_no():
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                print("Your pass list is empty!!!!")
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_no():
                checker(list_str_l_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_yes():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_str_l_1 + list_str_u_1)
        if ask_user_str_l in switch_case_no():
            if ask_user_str_u in switch_case_yes():
                checker(list_str_u_1)
```